# How to add page transition effects properly in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8

I added some page transition in my Application.but that is not working properly the transition is flickering while loading the page content.Page mainly contains image and text ,image is loading from a server.please see the below code that iam using

```
<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="BackwardIn"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:TurnstileTransition Mode="ForwardIn"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationInTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationInTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationInTransition>

<toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
    <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
            <toolkit:SwivelTransition Mode="BackwardOut"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Backward>
        <toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
            <toolkit:SwivelTransition Mode="BackwardOut"/>
        </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition.Forward>
    </toolkit:NavigationOutTransition>
</toolkit:TransitionService.NavigationOutTransition>
```

Any one have any idea regarding this,Please let me know.

Comment: Are you loading the image on UI thread?

Comment: yes iam jus binding the image source into the xaml                                       Like:  <Image Width="195" Height="103" Source="{Binding ArticleThumbImageToDisply}"  ImageFailed="ArticleImageFailedHandler"/>

Comment: Ok, is transition smooth if you don't bind the image. Let me know and i will provide you a solution.

Comment: yes.if page contains only predefined content the transition is smooth

Comment: you tried my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Your page transition is not smooth at the moment as the image is getting downloaded on a UI thread.

The work around is to bind any default local image first, for sake of looks. Then on `PageLoaded` event set the source to the `URI` or bind it then. 
You will notice transition is smooth and get the job done.